# Java Class to check if a line intersects a shape

Tags: java, api, line, shapes

Is there a class in the Java API that I can utilize to check if a line intersects a shape, given the starting and ending coordinates. I have tried playing around with Line2D objects, but the intersects() function for that class only seems to take in rectangular coordinates and Rectangle2D objects, which doesn't suit my purposes as my shapes can have any number of sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @Dan said you can check is your line intersects borders of your `Polygon` but you don't have to check intersect with everyline created by any two points from `Polygon`, just have to check intersection of your line with every pair of two point like `(p1,p2), (p2,p3), ... , (p(N-1), pN), (pN, p1)`. Polygon isn't created from all combination of points in array but from line from p1 to p2 connected with line from p2 to p3 and so on till line conected from pN to p1.

Some example here:

```
Line2D myLine = getMyLine() // some imagine method giving your line
Point2D[] polyPoints = getPolyPoints() // some imagine method giving point of your Polygon

boolean intersect = false;
for (int i = 0; i < polyPoints.length - 1; i++) {
   intersect = myLine.intersectsLine(polyPoints[i].getX(), polyPoints[i].getY(), polyPoints[i+1].getX(), polyPoints[i+1].getY());
   if (intersect) {
      break;
   }
}
if (!intersect) {
   intersect = myLine.intersectsLine(polyPoints[polyPoints.length - 1].getX(), polyPoints[polyPoints.length - 1].getY(), polyPoints[0].getX(), polyPoints[0].getY());
}
```

After execution of this code inside `intersect` you have value is your line intersects polygon or not.

If you accept situation when Polygon can contains a line and this still means that line (as a path) intersect the polygon then create java `Polygon` instance from your points (vertex) and just invoke:

```
if (!intersect) {
   intersect = myPolygon.contains(myLine.getP1()) || myPolygon.contains(myLine.getP2());
}
```

Comment: If my starting point was on the vertex of one of the Polygons and travels to another vertex on the same Polygon, then only checking the border does not catch this intersection right? Since each Polygon is a solid object, my path would not be able to travel through it and only checking the borders would result in a false positive. However, if I checked any combination of lines between the points of the Polygon, it would correctly catch this error.

Comment: Okey, so by intersect you mean that this line must start outside the polygon, goes through it, and end again outside?

Comment: Ohh... I understand - you think about the situation when one vertex of your line lays exactly at border of polygon, yes?

Comment: No, I mean it is not allowed to intersect the polygon as it is a solid shape. So your solution works well if the starting point it outside of the polygon since the borders will catch any intersection. However, if the starting point is on the polygon itself and the ending point is also on the polygon, then the border will not necessarily catch an intersection. This would mean that a line was able to travel through the polygon when it should not have been allowed to do that.

Comment: Hmmm, now i understand perfectly what you mean  but is this steal means that line intersect polygon or just that polygon contains a line?

Comment: I think since the line is a path, I would call it a line intersecting the polygon.

Comment: intersectsLine(..) should be inclusive regarding the end points of both lines, at least according to the javadocs

Comment: @AlexWien PointInPolygon method depends on this how many times ray from checked points goes through borders of polygon! If its even then point isn't inside polygon and if its oddit is, so please don't say that this method is inefficient if method which you suggest depends on this one!

Comment: I appreciate the help. I am still trying to think of how to properly implement this. From an outside point to a vertex is valid as long as it does not intersect the polygon, but the vertex being an endpoint would make intersection return true. Also, if a path moves from vertex to vertex, this is a valid move, but the intersection would again return true. I am playing around with the logic to see if I can get it to function as it should.

Comment: If you want intersect works as your write it's going to be much more difficult. You can check everytime when you get `intersect` true if this means that your line lays on border or border lay on your line or one point of your line is out of polygon but other one lay on border. More than if anything is `yes` from above it still doesn't mean that this polygon not intersects (with your assumption) the path. You have to provide more variables, for example `isEndOnBorder`, `isLayOnBorder` and set them everytime when this sittuation appears. At the end if only those are set your line doesn't interse

Answer (score 1):

You can check if your line intersects any of the lines given by any 2 points in the shape. So, you iterate over the shape points and build lines of any combination of 2 points. If any of these line segments intersect your line than your line intersects the shape.

Comment: I'm actually considering this solution at the moment as it seems to make sense in my head. I'm just imagining how this scenario plays out with a large amount of shapes. It seems like with each move from vertex to vertex, which is what my program will be doing, I would have to check every combination of points within each shape to see if it intersects with my path. I was looking for a more graceful solution, but if this is the best out there then I may have to play around with this suggestion.

Comment: You check for intersection until you find one that does intersect. You can stop at that point. There are definitely ways to optimize this.

Comment: If polygon will be created by lines connecting every two points it will be a chaos not a polygon

Answer (score 0):

The [`Polygon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.htmlanswer) object sounds like something you would like to use, but its `intersects` methods only take some form of a rectangular object (either corner coordinates with dimensions, or a `Rectangle2D` object). You might have to extend `Polygon` and add an `intersects` method that accepts a `Line2D`... or combine this with the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652337/java-class-to-check-if-a-line-intersects-a-shape/14652452#14652452) Dan posted.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to know the algorithm behind the intersects method in order extend the function to accept a Line2D parameter?